# Magento - Adding button to Product Edit page

Tags: magento, block

I am trying to add a button to the product edit page in the Magento admin. I know there are lots of tutorials out there (which I have used for reference) but I am trying to figure this out myself (with the help of SO of course ;) )

I have overridden the Product_Edit block like so (other module files omitted for clarity):

```
<?php
class Sulman_Addviewbutton_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit 
{
    protected function _prepareLayout(){

    parent::_prepareLayout();

    $this->setChild('sulman_test',
        $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_button')
            ->setData(array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Sulman Test'),
                'onclick'   => 'setLocation(\''
                    . $this->getUrl('*/*/', array('store'=>$this->getRequest()->getParam('store', 0))).'\')', // just copied the back button for now until I get it working
                'class' => 'back'
            ))
    );  
    return $this;
    }
}
```

This appears to be correctly extending the Product_Edit class because if I comment out parent::_prepareLayout(); none of the buttons render.
I'm just not sure why the button isn't showing. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The product edit form is rendered by the template `catalog/product/edit.phtml`.
You need to add some code in there also to make the button appear somewhere between the rest of the buttons.

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('sulman_test')?>
```

Comment: Perfect thank you. As you stated, I was missing the call in the phtml. All working correctly now. :)